# Divide by 4 for gallery

Tags: php, html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

sorry for asking here but I can't seem to get my head around what I need to do to complete this.
I have a gallery that is pulled from the database and i'd like it so every division of 4 it adds a new row.
Here is my website: https://creativehedgehog.co.uk/gallery

i.e

```
<div class="row">
col3
col3
col3
col3
</div>
```

Is this correct? Here is my code

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery cf">
        @php
            $i=0;
        @endphp
        @foreach($galleries as $gallery)
            @if($i % 4 == 0)
                {{$i}}
                <div class="row">
            @endif

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="{{$gallery->link}}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="{{$gallery->title}}">
                        <img src="{{$gallery->link}}" alt="{{$gallery->title}}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            @if($i % 4 == 0)
                        {{$i}}
                </div>
            @endif

            @php
                $i++;
            @endphp


        @endforeach

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found the problem that you were making a single row every fourth iteration by inspecting the HTML in my browser on your website, it is a strong tool for finding small mistakes such as this one. On chrome it is called DevTools, if you haven't already looked at it, I would surgest it, it makes the webdev life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a row element every fourth iteration, not placing 4 iteration into each row.

Look below:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery cf">
        @php
            $i=0;
        @endphp
        @foreach($galleries as $gallery)
            @if($i % 4 == 0)
                @if($i != 0)
                    </div>
                @endif
                {{$i}}
                <div class="row">
            @endif

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="{{$gallery->link}}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="{{$gallery->title}}">
                        <img src="{{$gallery->link}}" alt="{{$gallery->title}}">
                    </a>
                </div>

            @php
                $i++;
            @endphp


        @endforeach
        </div><!-- last row end -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use array_chunk function. [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
<div class="gallery-container">
        <div class="gallery cf">
        @foreach(array_chunk($galleries,4,true) as $chank)

           <div class="row">

            @foreach($chank as $gallery)
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="{{$gallery->link}}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="{{$gallery->title}}">
                            <img src="{{$gallery->link}}" alt="{{$gallery->title}}">
                        </a>
                    </div>
            @endforeach
            </div>
            @endforeach;

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let the bootstrap flexbox do their job

```
<div class="gallery-container">
   <div class="gallery cf">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">

        @foreach($galleries as $gallery)
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="{{$gallery->link}}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="{{$gallery->title}}">
                        <img src="{{$gallery->link}}" alt="{{$gallery->title}}">
                    </a>
                </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```